# /Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/geocoding_ios-2.3.0/ios/Classes/GeocodingPlugin.h:8:9 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

Tags: flutter, xcode, geocoder, pods

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGbRT.png)

I''m using all the latest version of the packages but still getting this error!

please help me

```
platform :ios, '13.0'
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'
project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}
def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end
  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end
require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)
flutter_ios_podfile_setup
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end
```

`geocoding: ^2.2.0`

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please add more details like what steps did you follow to install the library you're trying to use. For the looks of it, it seems the library is not installed. Maybe there are some steps in the documentation you missed or skipped. Please take a look at the libraries documentation to see if you followed all the instructions, or leave here what process did you do so someone can replicate the issue